# YAML merge 2 sets

Tags: yaml

Hey guys so I want to merge 2 YAML objects. Since these are not lists but objects with same keys I am having a hard time.  Consider these objects:

```
first: &first
  type: set
  options:
    first_item: one
    second_item: two

second: &second
  type: set
  options:
    third_item: three
```

I want to have another object has the same values of *first* but with added options items.

So can I achieve the resulting object below without having to type out both  object options again?

```
third: &third
  type: set
  options:
    first_item: one
    second_item: two
    third_item: three
```

Is this possible to achieve? Thanks :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use anchors to inherit properties. Here is a simple guide https://learnxinyminutes.com/docs/yaml/. You can find examples in the `EXTRA YAML FEATURES` section.

```
first: &first
  type: set
  options: &default_options
    first_item: one
    second_item: two

second: &second
  type: set
  options:
    <<: *default_options
    third_item: three
```